# Blazor wasm size too big

Tags: blazor, size, trim, webassembly

I created a Blazor project to showcase an app (I will make a web version of my app in the future), and I hosted the project on Netlify.

But the size of the release build is pretty huge.

Here's my project [link](https://fbxtelecommande.netlify.app/).

I tried to use the trimming option with:

```
<BlazorEnableCompression>true</BlazorEnableCompression>
<PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
<TrimMode>link</TrimMode>
```

And in the build log, the trimming is active:

> 1>PublishTrimmed                 = true

But the size of the build is huge.

[image]

I don't use nuget packages, and only IJSRuntime interface and NavigationManager class.

Also, in Debug mode, I get this log message:

> This application was built with linking (tree shaking) disabled.
> Published applications will be significantly smaller.

Did I miss something?

You can see in the network tab, all the assemblies of my project are downloaded.

[image]

Thank you.

Regards, Samih.

Comment: Did you actually publish the project in release mode? You shouldn't need to add any trimming/linking properties as they are the default for publishing.

Comment: Yes, I set my project solution configuration to Release, and I publish it.

Comment: You see, the message "this application was built with linking...disabled" indicates that it is not a release build/publish. How are you publishing?

Comment: The message appears when I started my project locally through "IIS Express". It doesn't appear when I loaded my project on Netlify, but my project size is too huge.

Comment: ah right, well can you share he network tab from dev tools?

Comment: Hi, I just edit my question with a screenshot of my network tab.

Comment: When I view that site, it downloads 8MB mostly brotli compressed. That is a lot for what appears to be a quite simple site - it's been a long time since I used .net 5 but I still have a simple site built in .net 5 that only downloads 40 files compared to your 180+ . You have WindowsBase.dll being downloaded - isn't that a .NET framework library? Why woud that be in your published app?

Comment: I really don't know. I activated the Trimming option, but a lot of assemblies I don't use, are still there.